# Difference in iOS OpenGl ES and Android OpenGl Es

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es

I am wondering what the difference (if any) there is in OpenGl ES for Android and OpenGl ES for iOS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenGLES API for Android have many unsported API and any problems.
For instance, glColorub, glPointParameterfv, point sprite OES(Extension) APIs, and so on.
And, Xpreia(android device) have glFlush bug.
When glFlush used, occurred display noise.

OpenGLES API for Android implementation is asunder each devices.

Comment: Just to ask you to expand on this, because I'm curious: do you mean that glColor4ub, which is in the ES 1.0 spec, isn't exported by the Java wrapper supplied on Android? If so, is it also unavailable under the NDK (where, presumably, you're using the C API)?

Comment: I've done many, albeit not too complex, Android OpenGL projects, from simple utility apps to pseudo 2d games (using ortho projection). Most of the code I've first done in regular desktop java (using JOGL) and then ported the code to Android. Never had I seen any such issues with Android's OpenGL.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference. The OpenGL ES 1.x and 2.x are available on most phones. Many mobile GPU have specific extensions but if you don't use them, iOS or Android can share same code. OpenGL is a C API, so the Java One provided by Android is specific.

Our games share the same code for iOS and Android. Only the EGL(Android) and AGL(iOS) parts are different. For performance reason, we use some specific extensions (Compressed Textures...).